# How to retrieve an Azure Function App's default host key from an ARM template?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-functions-runtime

I am able to retrieve an Azure Function App's default host key using the [/admin/host/keys REST API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API#host-keys-collection-resource-adminhostkeys) from Postman.

I obtain a token from Kudu using the deployment credentials and Basic authentication against `https://{{Function-App-Kudu-Url}}/api/functions/admin/token`. Then I include the returned token using Bearer authentication against `https://{{Function-App-Url}}/admin/host/keys/default` and receive the default host key.

However, I would like to retrieve this value from within an ARM JSON template. Googling has not proved fruitful in uncovering how this might be done.

It seems that maybe the `listkeys` or `listsecrets` function might work, but any parameters I provide to them do not return the key.

How can the default host key be accessed from within an ARM JSON template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to use the function host key within your function code, but moreover the function will output your function key as an ARM template compatible string, so you will be able to reference it inside your main ARM template.

Here is the function code, and adapted to get the input from the ARM template.

```
[FunctionName("GetKeys")]
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
{
  //get the publishing profile information from function argument
  var queryStrings=req.GetQueryParameterDictionary();
  string publishingUserName = "";
  string publishingPassword = "";  
  string hostKey = "";  
  queryStrings.TryGetValue("publishingUserName", out publishingUserName);
  queryStrings.TryGetValue("publishingPassword", out publishingPassword);
  //get the JWT token to call the KUDU Api
  var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{publishingUserName}:{publishingPassword}"));
  var apiUrl = new Uri($"https://{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE")}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api");
  string JWT;
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {base64Auth}");
    var result = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/functions/admin/token").Result;
    JWT = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim('"'); //get  JWT for call funtion key
  }
  //get the key from KUDU
  var siteUrl = new Uri($"https://{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE")}.azurewebsites.net");
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWT);
    string jsonResult = client.GetAsync($"{siteUrl}/admin/host/keys").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    dynamic resObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
    hostKey = resObject.keys[0].value;
  }
  var template = @"{'$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#', 'contentVersion': '1.0.0.0', 'parameters': {}, 'variables': {}, 'resources': [],
   'outputs': {
      'HostKey':{
            'value': {hostKey},
            'type' : 'string'
          }
        }
}";
  HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  response.Content = new StringContent(template, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  return response; 
}
```

For more details code, you could refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@mandur/get-azure-function-host-key-in-an-arm-deployment-template-1eb7ba03c083).

Comment: I have already come across that article and it isn't really what I'm looking for. I want to be able to obtain the Azure Function App host key and assign it to an application setting on an App Service that consumes the Azure Function App. I want to do all of that from within the ARM JSON Template, but it seems it isn't possible. Failing that, perhaps the next best option is to try and do that from a PowerShell script during the release process. We're using Azure DevOps for this.

Comment: Actually, upon re-reading that article, it may do what I need. Albeit, in a kind of hacky way. I will try it out next week, and accept this answer if successful. Thanks for answering.

Comment: This is a clever approach and does provide a solution to my original question, so I have accepted the answer. However once weighing things up, i decided to use a PowerShell script as a separate step in our release process instead. I didn’t really like that this approach requires creating an Azure Function to provide the key and a linked template to execute it. Using PowerShell feels like a cleaner approach that is easier to understand. I hope Microsoft provides a nicer way to do this from within an ARM template in the future.